# How can I get AWS Amplify's DataStore to sync between user sessions in React?

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

Using `aws-amplify@3.3.11` and `@aws-amplify/datastore@2.9.0` with Cognito User Pools, I can do CRUD operations on model instances, and confirm they make it to the cloud. However, the events don't seem to sync back *down* from the cloud when I'm logged in to the same account from another browser, creating a different user session. The one potential wrinkle is that my model uses two `@auth` directives:

```
type TestModel
  @model
  @auth(rules: [
      { allow: owner, operations: [create, delete, update] },
      { allow: owner, ownerField: "members", operations: [read]}]) {
    id: ID!
    name: String!
    owner: String!
    members: [String]
}
```

I don't *think* permissions are causing the problem, since I can see the state I expect for the different users when I reload the page. It's just that the subscriptions never seem to sync *down*.

I'm new to React, and just trying to make sure DataStore sync works the way I would expect, so this code is pretty sloppy. Here's how I'm setting up the subscriptions:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const dispatchDataStoreEvent = (msg) => {
            switch(msg.opType) {
                case 'INSERT':
                case 'UPDATE': {
                    console.log('TK dispatchDataStoreEvent UPSERT typeof ', typeof msg.element, msg.element)
                    dispatch(upsertOne(msg.element))
                    return
                }
                case 'DELETE': {
                    console.log('TK dispatchDataStoreEvent DELETE typeof ', typeof msg.element, msg.element)
                    dispatch(vaultDeleted(msg.element))
                    return
                }
                default: {
                    console.log('TK dataStoreDispatcher unhandled optype: ', msg.opType, msg.element)
                    return
                }
            }
        }
        const subscription = DataStore.observe(TestModel, c => c.members('contains', currentUser)).subscribe(msg => {
            dispatchDataStoreEvent(msg)
        })
        return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
    }, [dispatch, currentUser, testModels])
```

The predicate doesn't seem to matter, either – when I don't use it, the same expected behavior (sync events triggering from actions taken in a different user session) is missing. As far as I can tell, my auto-generated aws-exports.js file matches the [this subscription spec](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/graphqlapi/subscribe-data/q/platform/js). The CLI has a special section about [authorizing subscriptions](https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/auth#authorizing-subscriptions) but I'm not sure if there's another argument I should be passing in for my call to `DataStore.observe`. Does `DataStore` only handle what it calls ["[Observe] Data in real-time"](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/real-time/q/platform/js) in such a way that it never syncs changes down dynamically?

I can get the behavior I expect toggling my computer's network connection on and off. I just can't get DataStore to sync when changes are made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like it's an open issue with amplify-js, a limitation with using an array of owners as an auth rule: [DataStore with @auth - subscriptionError ... MissingFieldArgument: Missing field argument editors](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7069)